# How do you apply a sale/discount to digital products?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-digitalproducts

When using the digital products plugin, is there a way to apply a sale or discount to these products?

[This answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15811/5564) mentions a digital product only has a `price` property and not a `salePrice` property. Does that mean that it is impossible for a digital product to have some sort of discounted price?